# How do you combine videos at specific X and Y positions with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

If I have multiple video files, and I want to combine videos at specific x/y coordinates, how would I go about doing that?

I know that the `xstack` filter allows you to position videos using a column/row notation.

Say I have multiple different size rectangle frames, and I knew the x/y coordinate of the top left corner, how could I position these using that value?

See the image:
[image]

Comment: Besides column/row, xstack also accepts numeral constants in its expressions.

Answer (score 0):

As @gyan mentioned in a comment, you can use absolute pixel coordinates directly in the expression:

```
xstack=inputs=3:layout=0_0|720_0|0_540
```

[Documentation:](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xstack)

> [layout] sets position of each video input in output. Each input is separated
>   by ’|’. The first number represents the column, and the second number
>   represents the row. Numbers start at 0 and are separated by ’_’.
>   Optionally one can use wX and hX, where X is video input from which to
>   take width or height. Multiple values can be used when separated by
>   ’+’. In such case values are summed together.

Apparently, here 'column' and 'row' refer to the x,y coordinates of the top-left corner.